# How to get the complete Report from the Crashlytics

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Curerntly to figure out the affected smartphones from the crashes I have to go to each crash and select the manufacturer make and then thier models as attached.

[image]

Is there a way to look at or download the consolidated crash report stating all the crashes and the Affected phones.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. Not currently, but noted that you'd like to see it as an option.

Comment: Yes i do. Can you please tell how can we see the region information, like the user info to which part of the world he belongs

Comment: You would need to log a custom key prior to the crash. For example, set the language of the keyboard after Fabric has been initialized.